# I am getting an error from the javascript code: var context = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext("2d");

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on developing a game. However, I cannot seem to get the context of the canvas as I have before. My HTML file contains the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Nostalgia</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="gameStyles.css"></link>
</head>
<body>
  <canavs id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="gameScript.js"></script>
</html>
```

The javascript file is:

```
context = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext("2d");

const level = [0,0,0,0,0];
var xToDraw = 0;
var yToDraw = 0;


var img0 = new Image();
img0.src = "./images/tiles/grass.png";

var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "./images/tiles/dirt.png";

var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "./images/tiles/sand.png";
function drawLevel(){
  // solution
  level.map((item1) => {
    yToDraw-=16
    item1.map((item2) => {
      if(item2==0){
        context.drawImage(img0, xToDraw, yToDraw);
      }
      xToDraw+=16;
    });
  });
}
  drawLevel();
```

Note: This is being run using electron, the page is loading to the window.

The error that was being thrown was: TypeError: `document.getElementById(...).getContext is not a function`

I would appreciate any help in resolving this error.

Comment: The error is pretty clear; it probably means that `getElementById()` is not finding the canvas element, perhaps because the code is running at a point when the DOM does not contain it.

Comment: Didn't work I'm still getting the error

Comment: @Sacha and Pointy The OP has the script in the correct place, the canvas will be there and no need for the onlod. As the answer shows, the OP had a typo.

Comment: @NicksWorld Which browser and version are you using? If IE 9+, is the page loading in Standards or Compatibility/Enterprise mode? The error suggests that `getElementById()` is finding an element, but the element doesn't have a `getContext()` method. That at least could be because the [browser doesn't support the feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Actually the script is not correctly placed. The [only permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) in a html element is a single head element and a single body element. The script should be placed before the ending body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have misspelt your canvas tag:

```
<canavs id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

Should be:

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```